# Exception: Microsoft Excel has stopped working

Tags: excel, vba

There is an application running perfectly in Windows PC (desktop, laptop). But when I try to run this application in Surface, it gives me the error below.

[image: Microsoft stopped working]

I debugged the code and it gives error at the code where we try to lock the cell.

```
Public Function temp1()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "pswd"
ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        Sheets("Travel_Requisition").Range("B" & "2", "S" & "105").Locked = True
        Sheets("Travel_Requisition").OptionButton12.Enabled = False
        Sheets("Travel_Requisition").OptionButton13.Enabled = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="?Inapune2007", DrawingObjects:=False, _
        Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

End Function
```

It stops working when code executes the below line.

```
Sheets("Travel_Requisition").Range("B" & "2", "S" & "105").Locked = True
```

Comment: This would be hard to figure out because this is not a usual VBA error message. It is that Excel crashed. It might be a corrupt file. I had problems with `xlsm` files some time ago. Try to save the file as `xlsb` and then see if this issue persists.

Comment: I tried to save it as .xlsb but it does not work. Same error is there

Comment: How it cold be corrupted file if the same file is working in other PC's . It is not working only in tablet and surfaces.

Comment: I've seen many strange things with Microsoft products so it was just to make sure that it is **not** a corrupt file. Also make sure that you update Excel to the most recent version. If that dosen't work too I would say this is an Excel issue and hard to debug.

Comment: I am trying to solve this issue from 3 days . I just update excel  to the latest version yesterday only . but it does not work ..

Comment: One last thing I can imagine and you can try is build a minimal example to raise this issue: Therefor create a new Excel file, paste in this function only (btw you could change it into a sub I see no need for a function here). Name an empty sheet `Travel_Requisition` and see if the function causes the same exception. By adding more and more of the original Excel file you can try to figure out what causes this exception.

Comment: Which Excel version and build number do you have on the Surface and which Excel version and build number do you have on the other PCs?